# Bash subshell consumes stdin of the parent process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, subshell

Let's say I have a `main.sh` script that will be calling `one.sh` via a subshell.

`one.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

(if [ -t 0 ]; then
  echo "one little two little three little buses"
else
  cat -
fi) | awk '{ $1 = "111"; print $0 }'
```

`main.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                

set -euo pipefail                                           

main() {                                                    
  echo "one_result) $(./one.sh)"                            

  echo "one_piped) $(echo "the quick brown fox" | ./one.sh)"
}                                                           

main
```

Now, each of them works as expected:

```
$ ./one.sh
111 little two little three little buses

$ ./main.sh
one_result) 111 little two little three little buses
one_piped) 111 quick brown fox
```

But, when I pipe something to `main.sh`, I was not expecting (or, rather, I don't want) `one.sh` to know about the piped content, because I thought `one.sh` was in its own subshell in `one_result)`:

```
$ echo "HELLO WORLD MAIN" | ./main.sh                                                                                
one_result) 111 WORLD MAIN
one_piped) 111 quick brown fox
```

Is it the case my `if` condition in `one.sh` is not what I want? I would like `one.sh` to not create any side-effects of consuming my `main.sh`'s stdin - since now it has consumed it, my `main.sh` is now effectively `stdin`-less, as stdin can only be read once unless I store it away.

Thoughts? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, subshells (and other processes that a shell spawns) inherit stdin from the parent shell. If that's the terminal, your test will work as you expect; if it's a pipe then it will detect that it's a pipe and go ahead and consume it. There's no way for the subshell to tell whether it got that pipe by having it explicitly assigned (as in `echo "the quick brown fox" | ./one.sh`) or via inheritance.

As far as I can see, the only way to avoid this problem is to explicitly redirect `one.sh`'s input to something other than a pipe to avoid it inheriting the parent shell's stdin (which might be a pipe). Something like:

```
echo "one_nonpipe) $(./one.sh </dev/null)"                            

echo "one_piped) $(echo "the quick brown fox" | ./one.sh)"
```

... but what'd be even better would be to add a flag to tell `one.sh` whether to read from stdin or not, rather than trying to figure it out from the type of file attached to stdin:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Usage: one.sh [-i]
#   -i    Read from stdin

set -euo pipefail

if [ "$1" = "-i" ]; then
  cat -
else
  echo "one little two little three little buses"
fi | awk '{ $1 = "111"; print $0 }'

...

echo "one_result) $(./one.sh)"                            

echo "one_piped) $(echo "the quick brown fox" | ./one.sh -i)"
```

(Note that I also removed the unnecessary parentheses around the `if` block -- they created another level of subshell for no good reason.)

Answer (score 2):

By default, every process inherits its standard input (and output and error) from its parent. Input redirection and pipes are two ways to change standard input to a different file descriptor when starting the child process.

It is the responsibility of `main.sh`, if needs to read from its standard input, to know that `one.sh` *also* reads from standard input, and it will need to prevent `one.sh` from consuming it.

Comment: A possible workaround: set `one.sh`'s STDIN to `/dev/null` so that it cannot "steal" from the parent's input.  The result would look like `$(one.sh < /dev/null)`